# Derivative of dot product equals the negative cross product: does this occur elsewhere besides rotations?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-fields

The potential energy of a dipole moment $\vec{p}$ in a uniform electric field $\vec{E}$ can be expressed as the negative dot product of the two vectors, with $U = 0$ defined at $90$ degrees.
$$U=-\vec{p}\cdot\vec{E}.$$
The negative derivative of a potential energy function with respect to angle yields the torque, $\vec{p}\times\vec{E}$.
$$-\frac{d(-\vec{p}\cdot\vec{E})}{d\theta} \hat{r}=\vec{p}\times\vec{E}$$

where $\hat{r}$ points along the axis perpendicular to the plane defined by the $\vec{p}$ and $\vec{E}$ vectors, with sign determined by the convention of right-hand rule.

Are there other physical systems that have a similar vector relationship, where the derivative of a dot product equals a cross product of the same vectors? Or is there any broader mathematical significance to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The deriative of a dot product with respect to the angle between the vectors is

$$\frac{d}{d\theta} \mathbf A \cdot \mathbf B = \frac{d}{d\theta}AB\cos(\theta) = -AB\sin(\theta) = -|\mathbf A \times \mathbf B|$$

This is a mathematical identity, so it is always true regardless of what $\mathbf A$ and $\mathbf B$ are.  It's true of the work done by a force $W = \mathbf F \cdot d\mathbf r$, the electric flux through a surface $\Phi_E = \mathbf E \cdot d\mathbf A$, and any other dot product you find lying around.

Whether this identity is particularly *useful* is a different question.

Answer (score 1):

Your observation applies to any two vectors, physical or otherwise (except vectors that are aligned, in which case the meanings of $d/d\theta$ and $\hat r$ are not clear). It is easy to show this by realizing that your definition of $\hat r$ is the same as the direction of $\vec{E} \times \vec{p}$ (which is determined by the right hand rule) and that the magnitudes of the both sides of the equation are the same, which can be seen by writing
$$ \vec{p} · \vec{E}=pE\cos\theta$$
$$ \|\vec p \times \vec E\|=pE\sin\theta$$
and differentiating the first equation with respect to $\theta$.

Comment: thank you for your reply.  Do you know of other systems where the dot product and cross product are both defined concepts with physical meaning like potential and kinetic energy?